# How to post to an express api, a vue js form including text and file inputs too

Tags: node.js

here is the code on the form submit:

this is my created object using text inputs values...

`const plat = {name : this.name, desc : this.desc, price : this.price, vege : this.vege, category: this.category};`

```
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', this.file);

        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: null, // here i want to send my file and the plat object too
    
        };

        fetch("/menu/plat/add", options)
```

Comment: Problem finally solved!!!! while fetshing your api :  formData.append('file', this.file); formData.append( 'urBody', JSON.stringify(yourObject)  )..... and get the file with req.files.file[0], and get your posted body too from JSON.parse( req.body.urBody )

Comment: Don't forget to add your middleware in your route too, upload.fields( [  { name: 'file', maxCount: 1} ,  { name: 'urBody', maxCount: 1}  ] )